# How do you read all input preceding the CTRL-D sequence?

Tags: c

Using the system call read in C ,

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char data[128];
    while(read(0, data, 128) == 0){
    read = read(0, data, 128)+ read //counting the amount of chars read in 
 }

    exit(0);
}
```

I would like the input to terminate upon ctrl+d, that way a user can press enter and it will just go to the new line. Right now it is not functioning that way.

Read returns a integer indicating the number of bytes it read. How would I stop reading once the user press ctrl + d, in other words you can continue reading while pressing enter but only stop when ctrl+d is pressed and then return how many characters I read.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to look into nonbuffered input. [This site](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html) suggests disabling canonical (buffered) input using termios functions. Here's something I wrote using the sample code they provide. This will allow the user to input text until the Ctrl-D signal is read (0x40) at which point it will output the number of bytes read.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

void print_int(int num);

int main()
{
  struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
  unsigned char c;

  /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);

  /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
  new_tio = old_tio;

  /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
  new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHOCTL);

  /* set the new settings immediately */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);

  char buf[128] = {0};
  int curr = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 128);
  int nbyte = curr;
  while (curr && buf[0] != 0x04) {
    curr = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 128);
    nbyte += curr;
  }

  /* restore the former settings */
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_tio);

  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Total bytes: ", 13);
  print_int(nbyte);
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);

  return 0;
}

void print_int(int num) {
  char temp[16];
  int i = 0, max;
  while (num > 0) {
    temp[i++] = '0'+(num % 10);
    num /= 10;
  }
  max = i;
  for (i=(max-1); i>=0; i--) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &temp[i], 1);
  }
}
```

Note that in their sample code, they use `~ECHO`, but I assume you want to see the input as you type it, so `~ECHOCTL` will only disable echoing control characters (e.g., the ^D at the end of input).

Comment: [Link-only answers are highly discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please expand.

Comment: @adamdunson I can not use libc, and that doesn't make sense to me. There should be a simpler, straight forward way of doing this.

Comment: @netcoder - Except for when they are encouraged by the top contributor here.

Comment: @CoryKlein: It's irrelevant. Besides, he didn't encourage it either. As you can see in that meta post, the consensus in the community is that it's discouraged. Even if Jon Skeet would say otherwise, it's a community site, he doesn't hold any particular powers over it.

Comment: @netcoder - You're right. I think I just had a knee-jerk response to what appeared to me as a hypocritical link-only comment.

Comment: Its for an assignment. All I want to do is read multiple lines store them in a char array 2d and then simply print it back out. input stops upon ctrl+D

Answer (score 1):

When used with data sources like terminals, sockets, or pipes, `read` returns as soon as there is *some* data ready. The terminal driver normally makes data available on a line-by-line basis, so that's what your program gets.

If you want to read a specific amount of data, or read all data until a specific condition is met, you have to do it in a loop.

Comment: How would I tell the loop to stop once control d is hit?

Comment: Can you give me an example n.m, a simple one based on my code.

Comment: I have my read ==0, in a while loop, but ctrl r is not stopping it

Answer (score 0):

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
   /*do something*/
}
```